# For $P$ projective, $\operatorname{Hom}_{RG}(P,RG)\otimes_{RG} X\simeq\operatorname{Hom}_{RG}(P,X)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

In some reading, I have $P$ and $X$ modules over a group ring $RG$, and $P$ is projective. A line says, since $P$ is projective,
$$
\operatorname{Hom}_{RG}(P,RG)\otimes_{RG} X\simeq\operatorname{Hom}_{RG}(P,X).
$$

What property about projective modules implies this isomorphism? I thought about viewing $X\simeq RG\otimes_{RG} X$, but I doubt you can separate the tensor product out of the second slot.

Comment: This is not true if P is free of infofinite rank and G is the trivial group.

Comment: On The other hand, if P is projective and finitely generated, then yes, and you should prove it using, for example, a dual basis.